# Dropdown menu appearing (on the Master Page) behind the jquery-ui tabs (on the inner page): How to reverse that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I've a master page that contains a dropdown menu. on the inner page I've placed a jquery-ui tabs. When I hover the menu, the flying part appears behind the tabs.

How can I make the flying part display on top of the tabs so I can select menu options?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching on Stackoverflow, I've found out that the [problem has to do with z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784944/z-index-issues-with-jquery-tabs-superfish-menu).
After (i) setting the menu container's z-index superior to that of the tabs container and setting the position for both containers to relative, Everything was fine. Make sens as what I want is to have the menu flying out on top of the tabs.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer - just had the same problem myself :D